# Stop a DataGridCell from losing focus if there is an error and get error template on the DataGridCell?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid, idataerrorinfo

Is it possible to stop a `DataGridCell` in editing mode with a validation error--caused by an exception in the bound object's property setter--from losing focus until the user either a) corrects that error, or b) reverts their changes by pressing 'Esc'?

Also, while I can show a validation template for the row, I can't seem to get it to fire for the DataGridCell itself.

Here's our test styles. This works...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">

    <Style.Triggers>

        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

This Doesn't...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

    <Style.Triggers>

        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Here are our columns:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NameColumn"
        Header="Name"
        Binding="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
        Width="*" />

    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ValueColumn"
        Header="Value"
        Binding="{Binding Value, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
        Width="*" />

</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. ***Is it possible to stop a DataGridCell in editing mode with a validation error--caused by an exception in the bound object's property setter--from losing focus until the user either a) corrects that error, or b) reverts their changes by pressing 'Esc'?***

Yes, it is possible. We have to check for example, HasErrors property of our ViewModel where errors can be generated and set its value accordingly.

This answer uses concepts presented in a solution which I posted here :

[WPF MVVM Validation DataGrid and disable CommandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560693/wpf-mvvm-validation-datagrid-and-disable-commandbutton/32569524#32569524)

DataGridCellTemplate xaml code :

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
            <DataTemplate>                            
                    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Loaded="TextBox_Loaded" PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus" PreviewKeyUp="TextBox_PreviewKeyUp">
                            <TextBox.Triggers>
                            </TextBox.Triggers>
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                <Binding Path="ID" UpdateSourceExceptionFilter="ReturnExceptionHandler" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" >
                                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        <v:CustomValidRule ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue"></v:CustomValidRule>
                                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                </Binding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {        
          InitializeComponent();
          DataContext = vm; 
        }

    // This is wrong and will result in StackOverflow exception
    private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
             if (vm.HasErrors)
            {
               TextBox b = (TextBox)sender;
               b.Focus();
             }
    }

        private void TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {    
            TextBox b = (TextBox)sender;

            if (vm.HasErrors)
            {
                e.Handled = true;

                b.Focus();
                b.CaptureMouse();
            }
            else {
                e.Handled = false;
                b.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            }
        }               

        private void TextBox_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Escape)
            {
                TextBox b = (TextBox)sender;
                b.Undo();
            }
        }
```

Now, we need to check for errors and set HasErrors property of ViewModel at those places.

The errors can be generated at 3 levels in this order viz;

a. Exception thrown by the Binding engine while updating the value,

b. Custom validation before value reaches ViewModel.

c. Validation done in ViewModel against DataBase or something else.

a. This is typical encountered when a character is entered where number is needed. This is handled using UpdateSourceExceptionFilter.
Output windows shows something like this :

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'a' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=ID; DataItem='Class1' (HashCode=66068479); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
```

Our UpdateSourceExceptionFilterCallback : This we have set above in our TextBox.

```
      object ReturnExceptionHandler(object bindingExpression, Exception exception)
        {
            vm.HasErrors = true;

            return "This is from the UpdateSourceExceptionFilterCallBack.";
        }
```

b. This we do with our validation rules which we plug into . But how our ViewModel will come to know about these rules ? We will maintain a observablecollection of these rules and attach event handlers to these rules, so they can notify their ViewModel, just like we implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notify Binding engine. 
We add our rules to vm like so,
MainWindow.cs

```
        private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Collection<ValidationRule> rules= ((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).ParentBinding.ValidationRules;

            foreach (ValidationRule rule in rules)
                vm.Rules.Add(rule);
        }
```

ViewModel.cs

```
void Rules_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var v in e.NewItems)
                ((IViewModelUIRule)v).ValidationDone += ViewModel_ValidationDone;
        }



void ViewModel_ValidationDone(object sender, ViewModelUIValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            HasErrors = e.IsValid;
        }
```

c. Error checking at last level. We handle PropertyChanged event of all binded objects of our collection. This collection we binded to DataGrid.

```
void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((Class1)sender).ID > 7)
                HasErrors = true;
            else
                HasErrors = false;
        }
```

***2. Also, while I can show a validation template for the row, I can't seem to get it to fire for the DataGridCell itself.***

DataGridRow has ValidationErrorTemplate, whereas DataGridCell doesn't.